# ADFS 3rd Party Claim Provider Trusts - Disable/Expired Local AD Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adfs, claims

We have a federation between with our ADFS and the other company Azure AD using the "Claim Provider Trusts". We use the Azure AD to perform the authentication, but our ADFS/AD is sending some claims to our "Relying Party Trusts".

The problem I'm facing is if a user is disabled/expired in our local AD, it is still possible to authenticate and access the applications, because the user is not disabled/expired in the Azure AD. I can't manage the Azure AD and it is a valid situation where the user is disabled/expired in our AD, but still working on the Azure AD.

How can I figure this out to prevent disabled/expired user from my local AD to access my apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD you need to go to the user's profile and block the user's sign in under the user's profile > Edit > Settings

[image]

You do need to have at least the User Administrator role in Azure, so if you don't have access to the Azure AD you will need to ask an admin to do this.

You can also use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser) to set accountEnabled to false.

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
```

Body:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": false
}
```

Otherwise you can delete the user in Azure or ask the admin to do that.

Comment: Hi Marilee - I don't have access/manage the Azure AD - So I need to send some claim that tells the user is not valid to access the applications.

Answer (score 0):

For federation, the user should either be in your AD or in the other parties AAD.

(If you use AAD Connect, the user status is synched up to a shadow account).

Otherwise, you end up with this problem.

Is there a reason you have them in both?

Is there a way to match the AAD and the AD user?

If so, you can have a claims rule to get the status of the matching AD user and then deny access if disabled.

**Update**

You should read up on AAD Connect. It has filters e.g. groups so you can control who is synched up. Once that's working, if they are disabled in AD, then they will be disabled in AAD as well.

You should also look at the [application report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/migrate-adfs-application-activity) as it shows apps that can easily be moved to AAD and provides scripts to do so. There's a number of [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/migration-resources).

You could use the claims rules to find the enabled status of the user and then set a claim if disabled and then use the [Access Contol Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/migrate-adfs-apps-to-azure) tab to deny access if this claim exists.

Comment: The reason is because ADFS is where we have all our apps and I didn't want to have to update all of them and create new entry in the AAD for each app since it is managed by a different team. Let's say the ADFS if for our backoffice tools our business unit uses and AAD is the global company. The user email from AAD and ADFS are the same and that's where I do the queries and match/get the attributes to send to my apps. I can send over here some claims and the saml output I'm getting/doing maybe easier for troubleshooting and help. Will do that in the morning, thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using AAD Connect?

Comment: I'm not sure how that work. I decided doing this to avoid having to federate every single with our global company and instead federating our ADFS. So when we have a new app to federate, I just create/add to our ADFS instead of having to create over there, because to deal with that is so hard and full of processes, etc... our local AD is different than our company global AD and sometimes I have users in my local AD that are not in our global and not all global should be in our AD. The AAD connect will like connect both ADs and manage the users?

Comment: and also, it could be possible a user working in our business unit, so he/she has an account in our AD and one account in global company AAD. It happens that the user leaves our business unit to work in another business unit, so the account in our AD is disabled but the account in company global AAD is still enable, what means he/she should not access our tools anymore, so I guess the AAD Connect will not work in this case?

Comment: **c:[Type == "LOCAL"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:LOCAL");** should be possible to send a claim saying the account is disabled/expired and that will prevent the user from login?